# How to make command + shift + control + 5 video capture selected area on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, screen-capture, video-capture

Default picture and video capture shortcuts are logical:

[image]

Although it isn't among the default shortcuts, it follows that video capture of a selected area could use the following:

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

#### Question

How can <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> be made to:

1. allow the user to drag the cursor to select a portion of the screen (exactly like for picture capture of selected area),
2. once the mouse button is released from selecting the portion of the screen, start video capture of that selected area

?

#### Note

The difference with <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> (i.e. without <kbd>control</kbd>), is that it will bring up a menu for a video capture but the user still has to ensure 'Record Selected Portion' is selected, and use a fiddlier interface to select the portion of the screen compared to picture capture.

Comment: " it follows that"… no it doesn't. Capturing video to RAM would not be a great idea at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin from a UX / discoverability perspective it makes great sense, since it follows the preceding shortcuts. I never implied capturing video to RAM; the shortcut can do exactly as video capture selection currently does, just via keyboard shortcut, rather than requiring use of a menu and fiddly area selection interface.

Comment: meh, adding opt as you save removes the dropshadow., as an action it stores to RAM. [if you read previous versions of this post it took me a minute to recall accurately] You can script `screencapture` https://ss64.com/osx/screencapture.html

Comment: Oh, I give up [my bad, sorry] ;)) Adding Ctrl saves to RAM, Opt removes the dropshadow - not documented. (I'll get this right eventually ;)) One thing that '5' does that the others doesn't is it remembers screen area between sessions. I always use '5' for repetitive work.

Comment: @Tetsujin I completely messed up, I meant control (not option) the whole time! Fixed now.

Comment: & I'd been banging my head on the wall at the end of a very long day, not knowing my own ermm… base from my apex ;))

Comment: btw, if you set it to forget the selection you are given the same 'drag a box' interface as '4'. Whilst it's open you can then set it back to remember & it then will for next time.